# Can I redirect stderr when running or debugging python code in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, stderr

Can I redirect stderr when running or debugging python code in VS Code?  Sometimes I don't want to see all the messages that imported modules spit out. Very often they aren't helpful.  I'd like to be able to send stderr to /dev/null or another file sometimes, but not always.   I can run my python program that way directly in the terminal, but I want to do this when debugging so I can see my output without it scrolling quickly by.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the debugger press the configuration file down arrow.  It probably says current program.  Press add configuration.  Then towards the bottom of the json file add this:

```
 "args": ["2>/dev/null"]
```

Remember to put a comma at the end of the previous line.  Then run the debugger.

Comment: Since VS Code doesn't run the command in a shell, this will not work. It will simply be passed to the program you're running as an argument.